# Timeout exception while producing to a remote Kafka broker with Kafka client api 1.0.1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-compute-engine, kafka-producer-api

The producer-api(Kafka-client-1.0.1) cannot not produce messages in my remote Kafka broker (v1.1.0) hosted in google cloud.

I have configured the server.properties file, by adding the following:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<Local-IP>:9092
```

But same results.

My Producer Api looks like this:-

```
public class KafkaProducerExample {
private final static String TOPIC = "my-topic";
private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS ="Public-IP:9092";
private static Producer<Long, String> createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers",BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);

    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
    props.put("key.serializer",LongSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName());
    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}

static void runProducer(final int sendMessageCount) throws Exception {
    final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        for (long index = time; index < time + sendMessageCount; index++) {
            final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record =
                    new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, index,
                                "Hello Suvro " + index);
            RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            System.out.printf("sent record(key=%s value=%s) " +
                            "meta(partition=%d, offset=%d) time=%d\n",
                    record.key(), record.value(), metadata.partition(),
                    metadata.offset(), elapsedTime);
        }
    } finally {
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        runProducer(5);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The error looks like:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for my-topic-0: 30039 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:94)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:29)
at in.gov.enam.etrade.notification.KafkaProducerExample.runProducer(KafkaProducerExample.java:39)
at in.gov.enam.etrade.notification.KafkaProducerExample.main(KafkaProducerExample.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for my-topic-0: 30039 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

However, this entire thing worked when the zookeeper, Kafka-server and the Producer api were run on the same machine with localhost.

I have no clue what I have missed or where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this issue? I am also running into the exact same problem. Telnet works fine, means port is open. But the Kafka producer just keep timing out. Tried with hosting Kafka on 3 different machines, same results. if you have found the solution, can you please help?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue pointing to Kafka cluster deployed in Docker. It is because of access issue in between your local machine and remote Kafka cluster. If you are able to package your producer app, deploy/run it on the remote google cloud, the producer app should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from LAN, change the following 2 files:

In config/server.properties:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://server.ip.in.lan:9092
```

In config/producer.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=server.ip.in.lan:9092
```